# form validation in ie11 with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my form, I have a field that is required using Angular's form validation.  It looks something like:

```
<form id="project" name="formProject">
<input id="projectName" name="projectName" ng-model="projectForm.projectName" placeholder="Name" required />
<div ng-show="!formProject.projectName.$pristine && formProject.projectName.$error.required>
A project name is required.
</div>
```

The problem is, once the user puts the cursor in the input box, the error message immediately shows.  It doesn't wait for the user to start typing.  This is not an issue in Firefox or Chrome, just IE.  Is there an easy work around?

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: @runTarm 1.2 is what's in the definition file.

Comment: What is the third part of version? I'm not sure but I think this issue has been fixed already in angular version around 1.2.16

Comment: @runTarm sorry we were using 1.2 for the typescript definition file.  We are actually using 1.3.0 beta.10

Comment: It seems the problem would dissappear if the `required` or `placeholder` is removed.

Answer (score 0):

You could workaround the problem by initialize the value binding with the `ng-model` to an empty string.

Either via `ng-init`:

```
<input id="projectName" name="projectName" ng-model="projectForm.projectName" ng-init="projectForm.projectName = ''" placeholder="Name" required="" />
```

Or do it in a controller:

```
$scope.projectForm = {
  projectName: ''
};
```

**Example plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/jbXJSYuIaOBO037fsyzI?p=preview

Hope this helps.